# C# Snmp Trap Sender

Tags: c#, snmp, snmp-trap

I want to develop a snmp trap sender program.Previously i developed a windows service project.I want to that trap is sent a report to me about this service.Is that possible and which ways should i follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib

Download its source code and you can see the snmpsendtrap sample in Samples\C# folder.

You should be able to send traps directly from the Windows service application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [iReasoning MIB Browser](http://ireasoning.com/mibbrowser.shtml)? There are trap receiver and sender feature built-in, and they are simple to be used.

Hope it helps.